# c++ constructor no matching function

Tags: c++, constructor

```
struct structA
{
  StructA( const int a ) { ... } ;
}
```

and then my main struct :

**.h**

```
struct MainStruct
{
   MainStruct( int x, int y ) ;
private :
    int _x ;
    int _y ;
    StructA _s ;

}
```

***.cpp**

```
StructA( int x, int y) : _x(x) , _y(y)
{
  _s = StructA( x ) ;
}
```

What is wrong?

If I replace the `_s = StructA( x ) ;` with `StructA s = StructA( x ) ;` and remove it from private it works fine. Why is that?

```
 In constructor .... 
 no matching function for call to 'StructA'
                       _y( y)
```

Comment: Before you enter the body of the constructor all members must be fully constructed. `_s` cannot be constructed because it isn't specified with appropriate parameters in the member initializer list and has no default constructor.

Comment: This is due to the fact that when you declare a constructor with parameters, default constructor is removed by default (you then have to declare it explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All class members must be fully constructed before you enter the body of the constructor. `_s` cannot be constructed because it isn't specified with appropriate parameters in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and has no default constructor for the compiler to use with automatically generated code.

Quick fix: Use the member initializer list

```
MainStruct( int x, int y) : _x(x) , _y(y), _s(x) 
{
}
```

> If I replace the `_s = StructA( x ) ;` with `StructA s = StructA( x ) ;` and remove it from private it works fine. Why is that?

Because `_s` is now an [Automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) that only exists within the `MainStruct` constructor. It is no longer a `MainStruct` class member, so it doesn't need to be initialized before entering the body of the constructor. Note that while this compiles, it renders `_s` utterly useless to you as it is only visible within the `MainStruct` constructor and will be destroyed at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct structA
{
  StructA( const int a ) { ... } ;
}
```

means you need to provide an int to its constructor.

You `MainStruct` does not do this:

```
StructA( int x, int y) : _x(x) , _y(y)
{ //by here we need to default construct the _s but cannot
  _s = StructA( x ) ;
}
```

You can sort this in the initialiser:

```
StructA( int x, int y) : _x(x) , _y(y), _s(x)
{
                                        //^--- look
}
```